# Styling Attributes in android

Tags: android, styles, themes

Where can I find the list of styling attributes for all android components?

example:

@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle

android:titleTextStyle does not appear on the drop down when I edit it on XML.

looking for complete references for these, does anyone know where I should look?

Thanks devs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all the Android base styles here

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res

Answer (score 1):

All styleable attributes are here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html

All styles (themes) are here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html